# Create a project from existing source code?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I downloaded an open source library distributed as source code (Apache Crunch). I want to compile it to JAR. To do this, I need to import the folder containing many folders containing source to Intellij Idea.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't know IntelliJ, but search for an Import button

Comment: It's available in compiled form via Maven: https://crunch.apache.org/getting-started.html#maven-dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Apache Crunch is distributed in a Git repository with public read access, namely `https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/crunch.git`. Fortunately, IntelliJ IDEA allows you to import straight from a version control repository such as Git. On the project chooser screen, simply select the "Check out a project from version control" and provide the URL to the Git repository:

[image]

Alternatively, you can skip the version control route. If you download the source code some other way, you will find that since it is a Maven project. You can then simply use "Import Project" on the same project chooser screen, and navigate to `pom.xml` within the project folder.

If you don't see the project chooser, but IDEA opens a project directly, then click File->close project to see the chooser.

(I'm using Ultimate so there might be small UI differences to the Community Edition, but the workflow here should be either exactly the same or very close)

Comment: Thanks. How did you get this URL? I didn't find it on Google.

Comment: @AvivCohn It is from the Crunch project site, on [this page](https://crunch.apache.org/source-repository.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm unable to compile the project to JAR. I added an 'artifcat' (the module `crunch`) in Project Structure and tried to build it to a JAR. It produced no output. Any idea?

Comment: @AvivCohn You should build it through Maven, using goals such as `package`.